# Name of this jar?

Tags: equipment, fermentation

I love this jar for making sauerkraut.   Its mouth is as wide as the jar which makes stomping sauerkraut much easier than Ball/Kerr jars.  Its glass is thicker than Ball/Kerr jars as well. I bought it at a flea market while visiting Dalton Ohio so there is no one to contact to get another jar.  That is Amish country, so I am thinking it might be an Amish made product?

Can anyone identify the name this jar so I can find it on Amazon or google it?   I have searched Amazon for "sauerkraut" and ever other variation of fermenting that I can think of.  Nothing even similar comes up.

[image]

Comment: A search on "fermenting jar" brings up dozens of results for me, some of which are similar to your photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clips look a lot like my [Weck jars](https://weckjars.com/). [Here is one with a fermenting lid.](https://www.ozfarmer.com/weck-large-fermenting-lid-airlock-seal) However, I don't see the fermenting lid on the Weck site.

Comment: I found a place in the US selling the lids : https://cultured-living.myshopify.com/collections/weck-fermenting-equipment .  I'm not sure if they're official weck parts, official weck lids that were modified to add a fermentation lock, or what.

Comment: @Joe - just ordered more jars with lids from OZ Farmer.   Thank you very much for this tip.

Answer (score 2):

As already identified by moscafj, this type of jar is produced by two brands, Weck in Germany and Rex in Austria. You can recognize it by the closure system, the rubber color (e.g. Fido makes similar jars with white rubber, although I've only seen them as a self-contained clamp system) and the thick walls you mention.

I was able to find some resources describing these jars with keywords such as "Weck fermentation jar" or "Weck airlock jar", but the only place that seems to sell the whole system is in Australia. The cylindrical glass itself is available elsewhere too.

You might be interested in articles like this one: https://www.makesauerkraut.com/fermentation-lids/, it suggests alternatives to the airlock so you can use the jar with a standard lid.